# How can I change the properties of a DataGridTemplateColumn DataTemplate Element for a specific cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a problem with my DataGrid I created a while ago. The DataGrid shows informations about project tasks. Now I have to make the start- and end-date column editable. For this purpose I changed the DataGridTextColumn with the following code:

```xml
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Start"  Width="100" CanUserReorder="True">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <DatePicker 
        x:Name="DpStartDate" 
        SelectedDate="{Binding PlannedStart, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yyyy\}}" 
        IsEnabled="False"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

So far so good. Now the problem is that I have to check each row if the Task is in the right state to have the date changed. If so I have to enable the DatePicker. In the code behind I tried it like this:

```cs
for(int _i = 0; _i < DgvProjectTaskList.Items.Count; _i++)
{
      switch (((TaskListViewModel) DgvProjectTaskList.Items[_i]).Task.State)
      {
         case TaskStates.InWork:
         {
            DatePicker _dpStart = DgvProjectTaskList.Columns[4].GetCellContent(_i) as DatePicker;
            _dpStart.IsEnabled = false;
            DatePicker _dpEnd = DgvProjectTaskList.Columns[5].GetCellContent(_i) as DatePicker;
            _dpEnd.IsEnabled = true;
            break;
         }
         case TaskStates.Done:
         {
            DatePicker _dpStart = DgvProjectTaskList.Columns[4].GetCellContent(_i) as DatePicker;
            _dpStart.IsEnabled = false;
            DatePicker _dpEnd = DgvProjectTaskList.Columns[5].GetCellContent(_i) as DatePicker;
            _dpEnd.IsEnabled = false;
            break;
         }
         default:
         {
            DatePicker _dpStart = DgvProjectTaskList.Columns[4].GetCellContent(_i) as DatePicker;
            _dpStart.IsEnabled = true;
            DatePicker _dpEnd = DgvProjectTaskList.Columns[5].GetCellContent(_i) as DatePicker;
            _dpEnd.IsEnabled = true;
            break;
         }
      }
}
```

The problem is that "GetCellContent" return null everytime. So my question is how can I change the DatePicker in every row separately? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be able to do it this way:

```
var contentPresenter = DgvProjectTaskList.Columns[4].GetCellContent(item);
var datePicker = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(contentPresenter, 0) as DatePicker;
datePicker.IsEnabled = true;
```

`GetCellContent()` returns a `ContentPresenter` which first child is the `DatePicker`

---

If you try this it will work:

```
  foreach (var item in DgvProjectTaskList.Items)
  {
    bool enable = item.Task.State != TaskStates.Done;

    var contentPresenter = Data.Columns[4].GetCellContent(item );
    var picker = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(contentPresenter, 0) as DatePicker;
    picker.IsEnabled = enable;
    contentPresenter = Data.Columns[5].GetCellContent(item );
    picker = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(contentPresenter, 0) as DatePicker;
    picker.IsEnabled = enable;
  }
```

Comment: thanks Henrik for your answer. Unfortunately I still get null from GetCellContent(_i). I found another solution which works perfectly. Still big thanks for your time!

Comment: @A.Schneider: That's' fine: Have you removed the `as DateTicker` from the call to `GetCellContent()`? - `GetCellContent()`shouldn't return `null`

Comment: yes I removed it. I tried a simular approch today morning with object instead of var but still got the null in return. That null was the big issue why I couldnt help myself. Maybe its null because I use a DataGridTemplateColumn?

Comment: @A.Schneider: Ah, now I know what is wrong: instead of `_i` you should do: `DgvProjectTaskList.Columns[4].GetCellContent(DgvProjectTaskList.Items[_i])`

Comment: @A.Schneider: Perfect. But your own solution with a bound property to `IsEnabled` is in fact a cleaner and more MVVM-ish approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved the issue by creating a bool in the ViewModel and bound it to the isEnabled property of the DatePicker.